# SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'

Tags: node.js, graphql, babeljs, prisma

I installed babel packages as below.

**package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.8.1",
    "apollo-server": "^3.6.2",
    "graphql": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prisma": "^3.8.1"
  }
```

and I made babel.config.json file.

**babel.config.json:**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I did the same as babel `Node` API should be done according to official doc:https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

But I got the **error** message:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/server.js: Unexpected keyword 'const'. (40:0)

  38 |
  39 |
> 40 | const server = new ApolloServer({
     | ^
  41 |   typeDefs,
  42 |   resolvers,
  43 | });
    at Object._raise (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:569:17)
    at Object.raiseWithData (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:562:17)
    at Object.raise (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:523:17)
    at Object.checkReservedWord (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13044:12)
    at Object.parseIdentifierName (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13005:12)
    at Object.parseIdentifier (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12975:23)
    at Object.parseBindingAtom (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11037:17)
    at Object.parseVarId (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14216:20)
    at Object.parseVar (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14192:12)
    at Object.parseVarStatement (/Users/hayat/Desktop/chungchunon-backend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14009:10) {
  loc: Position { line: 40, column: 0 },
  pos: 814,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'UnexpectedKeyword'
}
```

It seems that due to the `BABEL_PARSE_ERROR`, it can't read `const`. But as I installed all necessary babel package, I can't understand why.

Comment: Why do you even need babel for backend? What version of NodeJs are you using?

Comment: I want to use the up-do-date grammar like `import`. so that I use babel. my node version is `v16.13.1`.

Comment: You can already do it without babel https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html I would suggest you not to use extra things like babel or whatever, until you really need it, because setup and maintain of them will cost you a lot of time

Comment: I checked your doc (and also checked there's import already), and uninstalled all babel things. But when run dev,  error comes : `import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

it says I can't use "import", which means I still need babel..?

Comment: Have you read the docs? Especially "Enabling" chapter. It says how to use them

Comment: Ok got it thanks a lot :)